# Data generator for tensorflow not working to get input from data from separate files

Tags: python, tensorflow, generator, tensorflow-datasets

I am trying to use a python generator to create a tf.data dataset using tf.data.Dataset.from_generator() to then be fed into a keras NN. The input data is a directory of files where each file is a numPy array measuring 815x815, and represents 1 input example. The Y labels are in the form of a one-hot vector for each example representing 1 of 54 possible classes.
The code for the generator to read each file is as follows.

```
#wavelet_filenames is an array of filenames for each input example, in the form "1.npy" up to "1259.npy"
def shuffle_generator(wavelet_filenames, label, seed): # input the Y_train filenames
    idx = np.arange(len(wavelet_filenames))
    np.random.default_rng(seed).shuffle(idx)
    path = "C:/Users/tslee/Python/whited_wavelets/" #folder holding all input examples
    for i in idx:
        data_array = np.load((path + wavelet_filenames[i]), allow_pickle=True)
        yield data_array, label[i]
```

tf.data.Dataset.from_generator() then takes in the generator specifying the array of filenames for training, and the array of one-hot vectors as labels.

```
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator( # for trainiing
    shuffle_generator,
    args=[X_train_filenames, Y_train, 66], #random seed 66
    output_signature=(
        tf.TensorSpec(shape=(815,815), dtype=tf.float16),
        tf.TensorSpec(shape=(num_classes), dtype=tf.bool)))
```

When I plug in `datset` as the input into a keras model, I get the following error:

```
File c:\Users\tslee\Python\IRP\Lib\site-packages\keras\utils\traceback_utils.py:70, in filter_traceback..error_handler(*args, **kwargs)
     67     filtered_tb = _process_traceback_frames(e.__traceback__)
     68     # To get the full stack trace, call:
     69     # `tf.debugging.disable_traceback_filtering()`
---> 70     raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
     71 finally:
     72     del filtered_tb

File c:\Users\tslee\Python\IRP\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\execute.py:52, in quick_execute(op_name, num_outputs, inputs, attrs, ctx, name)
     50 try:
...
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "bytes") to str


     [[{{node PyFunc}}]]
     [[IteratorGetNext]] [Op:__inference_train_function_37747]
```

What I tried instead of loading the files from the disk was to load them into memory and modify the generator so that it receives the input as an array measuring (n x 815 x 815) where n is the number of examples. Label is the same one-hot encoded matrix.

```
def shuffle_generator_mem(wavelets, label, seed): # input the Y_train filenames
    idx = np.arange(len(wavelets))
    np.random.default_rng(seed).shuffle(idx)
    for i in idx:
        yield wavelets[i], label[i] #returns wavelet(input example) and label(one-hot)

dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(
    shuffle_generator_mem,
    args=[wavelets, Y_train, 66], #random seed 66
    output_signature=(
        tf.TensorSpec(shape=(815,815), dtype=tf.float16),
        tf.TensorSpec(shape=(num_classes), dtype=tf.bool)))
```

This code works fine and the model runs as expected, so I am not sure why it doesn't work when the examples are tried to be load from file instead of off of memory.
Please help!

**EDIT:**
For the second case, I stored the separate examples in one .npy file and load it into memory with np.load(). The file contains an array with the dimensions (n x 815 x 815), so each row is a separate input example, and is read into memory as follows:

```
wavelets = np.load("C:/Users/tslee/IRP Data/Python/DATA/whited_hf_wavelet_samples.npy", allow_pickle=True)
```

Comment: Please provide complete example. How are you reading files into memory in the second case? Etc.

Comment: @Super-intelligentShade Sure, I edited the post to show how I loaded it in for the second case.

Comment: Well, that's not really helpful. Look at it from an outside standpoint. You say your files are 815x815 in the first case and Nx815x815 in the second. What if they are 1x815x815 and/or 815x815xN, for example? That would be the first thing I'd check. But I can't do that, since you are not providing enough data. You need to either provide a reproducible example, or at least enough data for someone else to build a reproducible example. Or as someone once said: [Help me help you](https://youtu.be/l1B1_jQnlFk?t=78).